# Error parsing a RDF XML file with rdflib in Python

Tags: python, rdflib

I am trying to parse this RDF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/celebrate_special_occasion/polarity">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://sentic.net/api/concept/polarity"/>
        <polarity xmlns="http://sentic.net" rdf:datatype="http://w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">0.551</polarity>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I am loading it from the URL: http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/celebrate_special_occasion/polarity

To do this I am using this code:

```
import rdflib

g = rdflib.Graph()
g.parse("http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/celebrate_special_occasion/polarity", format='xml')
```

However, the code return this error:

```
ParserError: http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/celebrate_special_occasion/polarity:4:67: Repeat node-elements inside property elements: http://w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type
```

Does anyone know what is happening? Which element is repeated? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be valid RDF. The W3C [validator fails](http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/rdfval?URI=http%3A%2F%2Fsentic.net%2Fapi%2Fen%2Fconcept%2Fcelebrate_special_occasion%2Fpolarity&PARSE=Parse+URI%3A+&TRIPLES_AND_GRAPH=PRINT_TRIPLES&FORMAT=PNG_EMBED).

I loaded it with [rapper] and got a more descriptive error message.

```
rapper: Parsing URI http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/celebrate_special_occasion/polarity with parser rdfxml
rapper: Serializing with serializer turtle
rapper: Error - URI http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/celebrate_special_occasion/polarity:5 - property element 'Description' has multiple object node elements, skipping.
```